# store and access variables with attributes in a loop in R

Tags: r, plyr

I have a small problem with my code. Here is a sample of my code. When I run the function, I get the following results. 
Also, I am using `raply()` from `plyr` package and this function returns output as a list-array. My code

```
EmpPval<-function(dat,numberOfPermutations=100,usePlyr=TRUE)

{

  if(usePlyr)
  {
    require(plyr)
  }

   if(usePlyr)
  {

statistic <- raply(numberOfPermutations,permdat(dat)$statistic,.progress="tk")
    browser()
  }

  else
  {    
    statistic <- replicate(expr=permdat(dat)$statistic,n=numberOfPermutations,
                           simplify=TRUE)
  }

 }

>statistic   #this is from one iteration

    [1] 0.0409457

    attr(,"numerator")

    [1] 0.0007954759

    attr(,"denominator")

    [1] 0.01942758
```

My result has attributes. Now my problem is I am unable to store these values as it is in a variable and I want to access them again like this:

```
s1<-attr(statistic,"numerator")

s2<-attr(statistic,"denominator")
```

The `permdat()` runs inside a for loop. So I will have 100 such values generated and I want to store all the 100 statistics values with their attributes. What I get now is something like this:

```
>statistic ##this is after it runs in a loop

[1] 0.028793900 [2] 0.073739396 [3] 0.049136225 [4] 0.058408310 [5] 0.027253176 [6] 0.019471812 [7] 0.071434025 [8] 0.038411458 [9] 0.028921401 [10] 0.021929506..... The attribute values are not stored.
```

Can someone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the results of `permdat(dat)$statistic` in a list instead of a vector. This will keep all attributes.

I highly recommend using `replicate` instead of `raply` as the latter will drop the attributes. If you specify `simplify = FALSE`, results will be stored in a list and all attributes will be kept.

```
statistic <- replicate(expr = permdat(dat)$statistic, n = numberOfPermutations,
                       simplify = FALSE)
```

Now you could access the single list objects with the `"[["`, for example `statistic[[1]]` will return the first object and its attributes.

You can return a vector with the values with `unlist`:

```
unlist(statistic)
```

Vectors with the attributes can be returned with `sapply`:

```
sapply(statistic, attr, "numerator")

sapply(statistic, attr, "denominator")
```

If you want easier access to the data, you can create a new object `s2`:

```
s2 <- unlist(statistic)
attributes(s2, "numerator") <- sapply(statistic, attr, "numerator")
attributes(s2, "denominator") <- sapply(statistic, attr, "denominator")
```

Now, you could simply use:

```
attr(s2, "numerator")
attr(s2, "denominator")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But when I try to store it as a list or leave it as a vector, I get the following error,  a list-array Error: Results must have one or more dimensions.

Comment: I have added the code to my Question again as I was unable to format it in the comments.

Comment: Sven,Yes thank you so much. This works well. Also with raply() I do not know what the error message is trying to say, but I tried this and it works and I am able to store the results and access them again. 

statistic<-raply(numberOfPermutations, as.array(list(permdat(dat)$statistic)),.progress="tk")

Thanks again.